# Creating heatmap for spatial overlap of features (or buffers of features) across different layers using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, intersection, overlapping-features, heat-map

I have several layers of features.  For example:

```
Layer1 -> set of polygon features
Layer2 -> set of point features (with buffer around each feature)
Layer3 -> set of polyline features (with buffer on both sides of lines)
```

Each layers has a level of importance:

```
Layer1 -> importance level of 3
Layer2 -> importance level of 5
Layer3 -> importance level of 1
```

I need to generate a heatmap in which the spatial overlap of features across the layers would signify a higher importance.  For example, the polygon created by the overlap/intersection of FeatureA in Layer1 and FeatureB in Layer2 would have a summed importance level of 3+5=8.

So the heatmap should show the spatial importance of all the polygons created by the overlaps of the layers.  What tools might make this possible, and what steps could I use to create this heatmap in ArcMap?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.  Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works. Thanks.